# WPF: How to distinguish between Window.Close() call and system menu Close action?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to distinguish ‘Window close button clicked (X)’ vs. window.Close() in closing handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361260/how-to-distinguish-window-close-button-clicked-x-vs-window-close-in-closi)

In WPF, here are different ways to close a `Window`:

1) `Window.Close()`

2) Select 'Close' from Window system menu (top left)

3) Click 'X' button on Window title bar (top right)

4) Keyboard shortcut: Alt+F4

All of these actions trigger WPF event `Window.Closing`

How do I distinguish between these two types of actions?

In Excel/VBA this is possible: `VBA.VbQueryClose.vbFormCode` vs `VBA.VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu`.

[This related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155782/what-is-the-difference-between-wm-quit-wm-close-and-wm-destroy-in-a-windows-pr) says the system menu actions will generate Windows event `WM_CLOSE`.  Perhaps there is a way to see the underlying Windows event from WPF.

Comment: Nitpick - you have "between two types of actions" and list of 3 ways to close window...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call HwndSource.AddHook to process Win32 message to get close reason of a Window.
Something like:

```
Window myWindow = new Window();
myWindow .Loaded += delegate
{
    HwndSource source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject(myWindow );
    source.AddHook(WindowProc);
};
```

And the implementation of the WindowProc:

```
    private static IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam,      
      ref bool handled){
     switch (msg)
     {
         case: 0x10:
              Console.WriteLine("Close reason: Clicking X");
         case 0x11:
         case 0x16:
             Console.WriteLine("Close reason: WindowsShutDown");
             break;

         case 0x112:
             if (((ushort)wParam & 0xfff0) == 0xf060)
                 Console.WriteLine("Close reason: User closing from menu");
             break;
     }
     return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

[And you have a list of all Windows messages](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessageList.htm)

[Values for wParam for WM_SYSCOMMND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

One simple option is to set some flag before calling `Window.Close` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this might also happen when you press `Alt +F4`;
If you are dealing with mouse event, then check and see mouse is over which element.